# libavcodec.so: has text relocations

Tags: java, android, metaio

I'm testing Android 6.0 on a Nexus 5 and i'm using Metaio (I know that the service is going to end on the 15th of december but for that date we'll move to another AR platform).
The problem is that when I start the ARActivity I get the following error:

```
    09-02 08:45:11.138: E/AndroidRuntime(6141):     java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: /data/app/com.myapp.myapp/lib/arm/libavcodec.so: has text relocations
    09-02 08:45:11.138: E/AndroidRuntime(6141):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372)
    09-02 08:45:11.138: E/AndroidRuntime(6141):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
    09-02 08:45:11.138: E/AndroidRuntime(6141):     at com.metaio.sdk.jni.IMetaioSDKAndroid.loadNativeLibs(IMetaioSDKAndroid.java:54)
    09-02 08:45:11.138: E/AndroidRuntime(6141):     at metaioCloudPlugin.SplashActivity.loadNativeLibs(SplashActivity.java:37)
    09-02 08:45:11.138: E/AndroidRuntime(6141):     at metaioCloudPlugin.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:68)
    09-02 08:45:11.138: E/AndroidRuntime(6141):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    09-02 08:45:11.138: E/AndroidRuntime(6141):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    09-02 08:45:11.138: E/AndroidRuntime(6141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    09-02 08:45:11.138: E/AndroidRuntime(6141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    09-02 08:45:11.138: E/AndroidRuntime(6141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    09-02 08:45:11.138: E/AndroidRuntime(6141):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    09-02 08:45:11.138: E/AndroidRuntime(6141):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    09-02 08:45:11.138: E/AndroidRuntime(6141):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    09-02 08:45:11.138: E/AndroidRuntime(6141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    09-02 08:45:11.138: E/AndroidRuntime(6141):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    09-02 08:45:11.138: E/AndroidRuntime(6141):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    09-02 08:45:11.138: E/AndroidRuntime(6141):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Does anyone know a possible solution for this or at least a workaround? 
I'm struggling to find a solution but I can't understand what the problem could be.

Comment: I met the equal problem with NDK ver r8B. Generated .so file contained TEXTREL section. But with NDK r8D I got .so lib without TEXTREL. You can check your library with command: `android-ndk-r8d\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.7\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-readelf.exe -a libhcsample.so | grep TEXTREL`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Today, I got the same error messages when testing my app with Android 6.0 on a Nexus 6 (Motorola). I solved my issue by checking the targetSDKVersion in the manifest file. Using "22" and not "23" as targetSDKVersion solved it. (See below)

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

I also checked the build.gradle files for compile version and targetSDKversion:

```
compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }
```

Hope this will help you. However, this is just a short term workaround for now, I hope that we will get some feedback from metaio though.

Regards,
christin

Comment: Yeah this is also what I did! I contacted Metaio and I hope on their answer about the problem if they have the possibility to find an easy fix for this but I pretty worried about it..

Comment: Fine that is working for you too! I have not yet got feedback from metaio. If you get some news from them, please keep me updated with a comment or message.  As far as I understand, it seems to be a Google/Android related problem (not a metaioSDK related one) as the native library libavcodec cannot be loaded upon app start. An exception is thrown which we then see in the logcat.

Comment: of course I'll keep you updated! Yeah and I don't know what we can do about that.. May I ask you, did you had the chance to use the Metaio SDK on IOS9? Because I haven't tried yet and I'm scared It will have problems too

Comment: Yes, I tried iOS 9 on an iPad mini 1. My AREL apps work as expected. I also tried some of my junaio channels. No problems so far. I tested tracking like Glue, LB/ GPS, GPS/ Orientation Tracking, Instant Tracking, Extended Image Tracking, Dummy Tracking.   Methods like setTexture(); startAnimation() + other animation handling methods, shareScreenshot(), startMovieTexture() are working. Starting full screen movies too. Reflection maps are also rendered. Setting 3D models to COS = 0 with screen anchor is working too. Hope it will be the same with your projects.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, this is a very good news! Wish I could upvote more than once :D Thanks again for your time and if Metaio decides to answer me i'll let you know!

Comment: AReallyGoodName has found a solution, check the answer below!

Comment: The textures in 3D models are not displayed. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: @user949884  Check the px size (should be a power of 2 size like 512x512 px), try a square PNG or a NON-progressive JPG. Otherwise, there is still the metaio helpdesk, until 15 dec 2015. You could search and look for answers, there had been plenty of similar problems.

Comment: @user949884 Or check the mesh of your model for backface culling. If the normals do not  point outwardly, the models' texture will appear transparent as they are applied inside and the rear side is transparent.

Comment: ok, downgrading the targetSdkVersion really works for this problem. But if I do this, google will not let me republish/update my app. What will be the solution then?

Comment: @christin What if i want to run my app with targetSDKVersion 23?

Comment: @Hiren Dabhi : I think you would have to compile the libraries (FFMPEG …) on your own to a shared object (-.so) and exchange the problematic -.so library with your updated -.so.  As for myself, I have not done this, I do not work with the metaioSDK anymore. As far as I know, it is still possible to publish apps at GooglePlay with targetSDKversion = 22 (Unity apps do so too) . But, it is not possible to use targetSDKversion 22, if the app had already published with version 23.

Comment: ok, downgrading the targetSdkVersion really works for this problem.

Comment: @christin what if i want to run my app with target SDK version 24??

Answer (score 15):

You can check if your shared lbirary has text relocations by doing this:

```
readelf -a path/to/yourlib.so | grep TEXTREL
```

If it has text relocations, it will show you something like this:

```
0x00000016 (TEXTREL)                    0x0
```

If this is the case, you may recompile your shared library with the [latest NDK version](http://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html#download) available:

```
ndk-build -B -j 8
```

And if you check it again, the grep command will return nothing.

Comment: How i can achieve this by using a tool or command prompt ? help me

Comment: Hi, i am having the same issue, I am able to see that TEXTREL message once i used that command. But not able run that ndk command i am getting this issue while running that ndk command:    ndk-build: command not found

Answer (score 12):

Previous versions of Android would warn if asked to load a shared library with text relocations:

> "libfoo.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents
>   security hardening. Please fix.".

Despite this, the OS will load the library anyway.  Marshmallow rejects library if your app's target SDK version is >= 23. System no longer logs this because it assumes that your app will log the dlopen(3) failure itself, and include the text from dlerror(3) which does explain the problem. Unfortunately, lots of apps seem to catch and hide the `UnsatisfiedLinkError throw by System.loadLibrary` in this case, often leaving no clue that the library failed to load until you try to invoke one of your native methods and the VM complains that it's not present.

You can use the command-line scanelf tool to check for text relocations. You can find advice on the subject on the internet; for example https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Hardened/Textrels_Guide is a useful guide.

Answer (score 12):

OK I've got this working here even with targetSDK 23 set.

For me and my branch the five files that required patching were

```
libavcodec\arm\fft_fixed_neon.S  
libavcodec\arm\fft_neon.S  
libavcodec\arm\fft_vfp.S   
libavcodec\arm\mlpdsp_armv5te.S  
libutil\arm\asm.S
```

I took the latest from https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg

You will also need HAVE_SECTION_DATA_REL_RO declared somewhere in your build for the macro in asm.S to use the dynamic relocations option.

Comment: thanks a lot!! I'm gonna test it as soon as I can and let you know!

Comment: For those on a completely different branch here's a link to the exact patches that ffmpeg had that fixes this issue, [link1](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/f963f80399deb1a2b44c1bac3af7123e8a0c9e46) and [link2](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/cb416a7d795414aaa534c27943bda0d3aef3b5a1)

Comment: Did this actually solve your issue? I applied these patches but still got the failure on M after recompiling my library.

Comment: Hi, Would you be able to share the lib files (.so) when you do the build ? I'm unable to get it to build at my end

Comment: @AReallyGoodName Could you please share the .so files. It would help us a lot.

Comment: Hey @Signo Could you please tell us how you compiled the .so files for android. I'm following [this guide to build ffmpeg using ndk](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/) but I'm unable to do so, stuck on it for days. I'm using ndkr10e. This generates .a files in android/arm/lib folder instead of .so files. Could you please point me in the right direction. Cheers!

Comment: @droidster i'm sorry but I still haven't tested this solution, I'm still using the targetSDKVersion = 22, you should ask aReallyGoodName how he did that

Comment: @Signo Thanks for replying. No problem.

Comment: @AReallyGoodName I've got the .so files but they have version numbers in the file names and they are referenced using those names from inside other .so files so they can't just be renamed. Can you please tell us how you compiled .so files without versioning. Sorry about all the comments. :)

Comment: @AReallyGoodName I have built newest ffmpeg libraries and now I have new UnsatisfiedLinkError: "cannot locate symbol 'avcodec_register_all' " referenced by libmetaiosdk.so . Does it mean there is still relocations from metaio's so library? Have you succsessfully tried it? And where HAVE_SECTION_DATA_REL_RO should be declared and with what value?

Comment: @AReallyGoodName can you tell me how to use this? already my app is live with `compileSdkVersion 25`. I have add ffmpeg library. now i have change  targetSdk to `23` . but this not compress video in marshmellow and nougat . My ffmpeg command is as follows . ` {"ffmpeg","-y","-i","/storage/emulated/0/Download/Nature_Beautiful_short_video_720p_HD.mp4","-strict","-2","-vcodec","libx264","-preset","ultrafast","-acodec","aac","-ar","44100","-ac","1","-b:a","72k","-s","480x480","-aspect","1:1","-r","24","/storage/emulated/0/KhetiVadi/videoCompress/d272264d84d2c06f2bcd9f0c8471075a.mp4"}`

Answer (score 6):

After a long time struggling and trying to compile FFmpeg in different ways, I found the solution. Make sure to compile FFmpeg with the --disable-asm flag. This will make sure that FFmpeg wouldn't have text relocations and won't crash when compiling against Android M (SDK 23)

To make sure it worked, you can use readelf as mentioned above.

Cheers

Comment: Hi i am using windows machine, can you let us know how to recompile the source, if it could be done in Linux/Ubuntu only kindly let me know a valid latest steps for the building.
Right now i am using prebuilt .so libraries provided with ffmpeg4android_demo, I am stuck at same position that you were,
I tried compiling the source but it was a fail.
If you have your own fork kindly guide.

Comment: You have to compile ffmpeg alone and don't use pre-built .so because they will still have the text relocations problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input.

Comment: No problem, let me know if it helped

Comment: A note to anyone who sees this in the future - using -disable-asm with FFmpeg results in a performance hit. See this discussion thread on the FFmpeg issue tracker: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4928

Comment: @Ozzz I am using Videokit library. Can you please let me know how can I compile FFMpeg with the --disable-asm flag on?

Comment: I have never used this lib but it looks like that the Videokit library is already taking care of that because their sample code has a compileSdkVersion 25.

Comment: how to compile the .so file to remove the text relocation error?@Ozzz

Comment: Make sure to compile FFmpeg with the --disable-asm flag.

Comment: @Arun please tell the way how to implement this in android project .

Comment: @Dharmishtha, quite delayed to reply you, Please use prebuilt library rather than trying to compile on your own. please let me know your issue in detail if still any.

Answer (score 2):

I received feedback from metaio's SDK team. They say that this issue cannot be easily solved by metaio, as it is related to the FFMpeg library. We would have to hope that an update of FFMpeg would fix the issue. 
I assume that we have to wait for such an update and to exchange the library files in the app.

I have not yet looked for a FFMpeg developer contact forum to make enquiries or to notify a bug. Do you know one by accident?

Best regrads, christin

Comment: Thanks again for your time! Excuse me if I didn't gave you news but I still haven't received any answer from the Metaio team. Unfortunately I don't know any FFMpeg forum so I can't help you.. I hope we'll get an update but i'm pretty skeptical about it.. If I have any news i'll answer you here! Thanks again!!

Comment: I have tryed new updated FFMpeg libraries. 
Now it gives another error:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "avcodec_register_all" referenced by "/data/app/it.productlab.card-1/lib/arm/libmetaiosdk.so"... 
Looks like there are references from within libmetaiosd.so file, meaning that all so libraries was compiled in tandem with metaio library, and it can not be solved without metaio now....

Comment: Maybe it's the FFMpeg version.