# Zbar scanner not supported for Android 6.0

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, android-sdk-2.3, zbar, zbar-sdk

when i click the scan ,its throw error like , But previous versions till lollipop its working good .

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: /data/app/xxxxxxx-xxx/lib/arm/libiconv.so: has text relocations
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
    at me.dm7.barcodescanner.zbar.ZBarScannerView.<clinit>(ZBarScannerView.java:33)
    at com.xxx.xxx.SimpleScannerActivity.onCreate(SimpleScannerActivity.java:101)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6248)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1125)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2437)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

while executing the below code

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("iconv");
    }
```

My TargetSDK version is 23 . If i change into 22 its working fine

Please do the needful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [libavcodec.so: has text relocations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346402/libavcodec-so-has-text-relocations)

Comment: I am using zbar and it is working perfectly on Android MarshMallow

Comment: show me your code i can help you

Comment: my target sdk version -23 . thats issue if i change into 22 .its working

Comment: i can't downgrade my target sdk version . because its already on playstore .

Comment: @AbdulBasith how you solved this issue?same problem is with me

Answer (score 4):

1、download the latest zbar project [here](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner)

2、grab the latest .so from barcodescanner/zbar/src/main/jniLibs

this works for me

Answer (score -1):

I have one solution, I know it's not that great, but it works.

Change your Build Version from 23 to 22 in your app gradle file.

Replace

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
}
```

With

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 22
  buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"
}
```