# Can't load vlcjni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList couldn't find "libvlcjni.so"

Tags: android, java-native-interface, libvlc, vlc-android

After extending support for Android 6.0+.

The app is getting crash while playing video using [VLC-SDK](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-android).

Previously we have make changes in SDK library a little bit as per our project need. Hence can't make changes in vlc-SDK.

I have tried the solutions as below:

1. Adding ABI filters.
2. Add gradle.properties file in project.
3. Add `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true;` in gradle.properties
4. Adding abi filters in build.gradle.

Comment: Why does this question has C tag?

Comment: @lolbas actually i have jni libtrary in my project which contains c files. But now i have removed that tag.

Comment: I also had same issue did u find out solution

Comment: what device are you running it on?

Comment: @Jon Its working fine at android 5.0 and below but from android 6.0 and above its crashing

Comment: possible permission issue ? can you share crash traces ?

Comment: Please post the logcat for the crash.

Comment: And yes, did you check this? - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43057517/3145960

Comment: [Check this answer you may forgot to obfuscate in progaurd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53931724/4060580)

Answer (score 0):

This means that the compiled abi binary specific for the device being run on is not found in the APK. As a start check the APK in Android Studio using APK Analyzer (or just drag the APK from inside `app/build/outputs/apk/` to the middle) and see within the `lib/` folder the abi's that have been compiled. If your device abi is not listed within the `lib/` folder, then that's the cause of your error and should do further checking like within the generated build files if it's missing (usually within `.externalNative`).

Comment: We know that we are missing with those abis. But it will be helpful for us how did we resolve this .so generation issue.