# Android Can't load vlcjni library (libVLC)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard

I can't use

```
implementation 'de.mrmaffen:libvlc-android:2.1.12@aar'
```

if the set `minifyEnable` to `true`.

The error message is

> Can't load vlcjni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNI_ERR returned from JNI_OnLoad in "/data/app//lib/arm64/libvlcjni.so"

How can I use `minifyEnable true` with **libvlc**?

Answer (score 6):

if you obfuscate the `libvlc` there is no way for the native code to find the necessary classes and methods so it returns a `JNI_ERR`. You just need to exclude the `libvlc` from `ProGuard`, add this line in `progaurd` file

```
-keep class org.videolan.libvlc.** { *; }
```