# readlink('/proc/self/fd/21') failed: Permission denied [fd=21] error in Android 6 after adding Admob module to Appcelerator app

Tags: android, admob, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-android

im creating app in appcelerator studio. It worked without errors on my Android 6 Lenovo a7000, until I added admob module to it. Now Im getting these errors:

```
[ERROR] :  linker: readlink('/proc/self/fd/21') failed: Permission denied [fd=21]
[ERROR] :  linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/data/app/com.techintegrity.ekko-1/lib/arm/libti.admob.so". Will use given name.
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: (KrollRuntimeThread) [77,153] Sending event: exception on thread: KrollRuntimeThread msg:java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: /data/app/com.techintegrity.ekko-1/lib/arm/libti.admob.so: has text relocations; Titanium 5.2.0,2016/02/20 08:05,384775e
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: /data/app/com.techintegrity.ekko-1/lib/arm/libti.admob.so: has text relocations
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Runtime.loadExternalModules(V8Runtime.java:132)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Runtime.initRuntime(V8Runtime.java:99)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime.doInit(KrollRuntime.java:205)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime$KrollRuntimeThread.run(KrollRuntime.java:114)
```

I have updated everything: appcelerator studio, titanium sdk, node.js, but the problem is still the same. found few people with similar error, but nothing that worked for them seems working for me. Thanks for any help

Comment: I got a similar error, which is resulting in that I can not start the app.
`E/linker(28319): readlink('/proc/self/fd/24') failed: Permission denied [fd=24]
    E/linker(28319): warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/mnt/asec/com.appdev-1/lib/arm/libstlport_shared.so". Will use given name.
    E/linker(28319): readlink('/proc/self/fd/24') failed: Permission denied [fd=24]
    E/linker(28319): warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/mnt/asec/com.appdev-1/lib/arm/libkroll-v8.so". Will use given name.`

Comment: is there a newer version of that admob module? http://stackoverflow.com/a/32873895/995891 Makes me think it's a admob's fault.

Comment: Since this page came up a lot when searching for a similar AdMob issue with Unity.. Everything started working after changing the API Compatibility Level to .NET 4.x. These readlink/permission denied errors were still in the logs though, so I think they may be safely ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Add following code to your config.xml.

```
<property name="run-on-main-thread" type="bool">true</property>
```

This will solve the problem

Comment: Sorry, Add this <property name="run-on-main-thread" type="bool">true</property>

Comment: where this property need to be added ,i cant find any such file inside android studio project