# Crash on using Zbar library in my application . Showing error when scanning QRcode

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, zbar-sdk

Error: 
libiconv.so: has text relocations ,
libzbarjni.so: has text relocations

[check error in view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRK5n.png)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346402/libavcodec-so-has-text-relocations

Comment: Hey, @MuhibPirani , I can't find proper solution with your link. I am right now using Nogut version. Can You suggest me something else.

Comment: did you try this https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner

Comment: yes, i'hv tried it already. But it is not working in iphone.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error messages when testing my app with Android 6.0. I solved my issue by checking the targetSDKVersion in the manifest file. Using "22" and not "23" as targetSDKVersion solved it.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

I also checked the build.gradle files for compile version and targetSDKversion:

```
android {
     compileSdkVersion 23
     buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.android.live'
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0.0'
    multiDexEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: But If I want to use targetSdkVersion more than 22 than what to do ?

Comment: android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.XXX.XXX"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }  using this in my build.gradle but still gettng error.

Comment: @gautham10794 ,  your solution is not working when I'am using above sdk version , would you like to suggest me something different .

Comment: This issue cannot be easily solved by metaio, as it is related to the FFMpeg library. We would have to hope that an update of FFMpeg would fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Follow me and solve this problem permanently! (Works well targetSdkVersion 25, buildToolsVersion '25.0.3', compileSdkVersion 25)

1.Download the latest ZBar project [here](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner)

2.grab the latest .so from barcodescanner/zbar/src/main/jniLibs, and replace the relative .so in your project.

3.Run your app!